# Regex to remove specific params from tags

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for a RegEx to remove a parameter value from within the specific attribute within a specific tag only. e.g.

```
<TAG1 atr1="param1: value1; param2: value; param3: value3;" attr2="value4">
<TAG2 attr2="value4" atr1="param1: value1; param2: value; param3: value3;" >
```

should result in

Comment: Okay, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm new to Regex. Got following 
(<body)\sstyle\s*=\s*(["']).*?\2(.*?>)
but it removes entire STYLE attribute if it is adjacent to BODY tag

Comment: SO is wrong place for it... In general it is very hostile for attempts to parse HTML with regular expressions. Consider looking somewhere else.

Comment: I know using RegEx might not be best suited for such a scenario but we don't have a release planned anytime soon and we need some temp working patch for few months. We can then rely on HTMLAgilityPack to work with the HTML doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HEIGHT: \d+[^;]+;` will match `HEIGHT: 218px;` in `<body style="HEIGHT: 218px; margin: 0px; background-color: #ffffff;" jQuery111105496473080628138="10">`

Something like this could get you going:
`(HEIGHT:\s*\d{1,}[^;]*;)(?<=<body.*style="[^"]*)(?=[^"].*"\s*>)`

Which *~translates~* to :

Capture: `(HEIGHT:\s*\d{1,}[^;]*;)`

If preceded by: `(?<=<body.*style="[^"]*)`

And followed by: `(?=[^"].*"\s*>)`

Implemented in code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string string1 = "<body style=\"HEIGHT: 218px; margin: 0px; background-color: #ffffff;\" jQuery111105496473080628138=\"10\">";
    string string2 = "<body jQuery111105496473080628138=\"10\" style=\"HEIGHT: 218px; margin: 0px; background-color: #ffffff;\" >";
    string string3 = "<test style=\"HEIGHT: 218px; margin: 0px; background-color: #ffffff;\" jQuery111105496473080628138=\"10\">";
    List<string> theList = new List<string> { string1, string2, string3 };

    Regex heightMatchingRegex = new Regex("(HEIGHT:\\s*\\d{1,}[^;]*;)(?<=<body.*style=\"[^\"]*)(?=[^\"].*\"\\s*>)");

    foreach (string item in theList)
    {
        if (heightMatchingRegex.IsMatch(item))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The match: " + heightMatchingRegex.Match(item));
            Console.WriteLine("Original: " + item);
            Console.WriteLine("Modified: " + heightMatchingRegex.Replace(item, ""));
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The fiddle to try it out:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/CIgByr

Comment: Thanks a ton!!! It worked.